# Store File into MySql using path

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE img (id varchar(29) ,imgFile mediumblob, PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

I tried to put a picture from phpmyadmin using the graphic insert and it makes this query:

```
INSERT INTO img(id, imgFile) VALUES('first', 0xe212d.......8f);
```

Up to here works good, but I want to put the file using a path; to do this I use this query:

```
INSERT INTO img (id,imgFile) VALUES('1221', LOAD_FILE('/home/myname/img.jpg'));
```

but it gives me this error: #1048 - Column 'imgFile' cannot be null. 
On mySql documentation says that the problem is due by privileges of the file, but I don't understand how to give them to the file 
I'm using UBUNTU linux

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_file

Answer (score 0):

All conditions that http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file lists must be met. Use the output of SHOW GRANTS

```
SHOW GRANTS
```

to look at the `FILE` privilege. Use [SHOW VARIABLES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-variables.html)

```
SHOW VARIABLES
```

to get the values of [max_allowed_package](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) and [secure_file_priv](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv).

With the default values your image file could have maximal 1 MB for MySQL until 5.6.5. And don't forget, your file must be readable by all.

Comment: I did:  SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=33554432; this works,       but this : SET GLOBAL secure_file_priv='/home/myname'; It gives me this error #1238 - Variable 'secure_file_priv' is a read only variable

Comment: Is `secure_file_priv` set. If the answer is yes, what's the current value?

Comment: It is null like before, when i try to change this value mysql says: Variable 'secure_file_priv' is a read only variable

Comment: It's not set, that's ok. Remember, this variable restricts the directory from with `LOAD_FILE` can read. But what about `SHOW GRANTS`. Has the current user the file privilege?

Comment: when i do show grants, it gives me this lines:                    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*73287338230919E4023289DFAC8A3FCA1AEFE7FD' WITH GRANT OPTION
GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION